# iOS: NSMutableDictionary propery won't set

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

For some reason I can't get an array added to a nsmutabledictionary. I have it declared as a property in my .h file here:

```
@interface TCMExhibitFeedStore : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *allLevels;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *storedLevels;

+ (TCMExhibitFeedStore *)sharedStore;

- (void)fetchExhibtFeedWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *obj, NSError *err))block;
- (TCMLevel *)createLevel:(TCMLevelRemote *)l;
- (TCMExhibit *)createExhibit:(TCMExhibitRemote *)e;

- (BOOL)saveChanges;

@end
```

Then, I'm trying to add an empty array to it in a function in the .m file like this

```
[_storedLevels setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"levels"];
```

However, when I step through the application this never gets added. Looking in the debugger shows it as

```
_storedLevels   NSMutableDictionary *   0x00000000
```

NSMutableDictionaries are nothing new to me. I'm just going a bit crazy trying to find my error because this all looks normal to me.

Comment: The above line attempts to set a mutable array as the value of the key "levels" in the dictionary _storedLevels.  It fails, however, since _storedLevels is nil, having never been initialized.  (Note that it's foolish to attempt to "daisy chain" statements together when debugging, especially if you don't really understand what you're doing.  Do one operation per statement, and put each statement on a separate line.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lines confuses me...

```
[_storedLevels setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"levels"];
```

Instead of above Use:

```
 self.storedLevels = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [self.storedLevels setObject:... forKey:@"levels"];
```

---

**NOTE:** Whenever you see **0x00000000**

This means your object is not `alloc`-ated.

Therefore you need to alloc+init them, before setting any array/value to them.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was some mundane detail I had missed.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR - Not at all "mundane" -- understanding initialization is very critical.

Answer (score 2):

`0x00000000` means `nil`. All properties and instance variables of Objective C objects are initialized to nil. Hence, we can tell that you have never initialized your properties.

You can to initialize the dictionaries in the designated initializer for `TCMExhibitFeedStore`. (Or before you access them to add elements)

```
self.storedLevels = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
self.allLevels = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```